# Gnuplot for time-based data

Tags: time, plot, gnuplot

I have a data set where each line contains an activation and deactivation time and a corresponding data type.

```
activation 05/08/2015 08:05:14.186  deactivation    05/08/2015 08:14:18.582     type 1
activation 21/08/2015 20:40:31.851  deactivation    21/08/2015 21:37:05.946     type 2
activation 03/08/2015 12:56:06.660  deactivation    04/08/2015 01:50:14.610     type 1
...
...
...
```

I would like to make a plot of duration of process for individual types. 
Ideally I would like to see time slots of activation for all individual types in one single plot. Since a specific type is not always active, I would expect to see a discontinuous plot where line indicates that it is active.

I was wondering if this is possible using gnuplot? 
I am familiar with gnuplot but I am not an expert.
How can I make a plot when the time data is of this format? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not really clear what you want. How many types are there? You can check the type value with the `stringcolumn()` function and `eq` string equality operator.
But to draw a continuous line, you need all the values in consecutive lines. You at least have to sort the file by type.

Comment: Should be nice to know under which kind of operating system you want to run it... with Linux you can use a wide range of external tools as filter for your data `plot "< sort myfile | bash myscript.sh | ..."`